# Win32 API Edit Control text prediction

Tags: c++, winapi, editcontrol

I was thinking of creating some text prediction for Edit control in winapi and now I'm wondering if such thing already exists. *I can't find anything about it.*

My idea was to use another Edit control which would appear below the "main" Edit control and I would just use std::find to search in a list of the words I want the second editbox to predict me.
Or just subclass the main edit control and do it that way, that is not so important.

**So my final question is, does something like text prediction edit control exist? If not, what is the best way to create it?**

Comment: @SergeBallesta I don't want anyone to write the code for me therefore I asked for the best way to do it, not for code. I looked in the documentation right before writing the question and after reading your comment, I looked at it again - I can only see RichEdit is capable of text correction, but neither Edit and Richedit are capable of text predicting.

Comment: Look at [Autocomplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884.aspx).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I have read the whole comment, my english is just no so great so I maybe didn't get everything. I know, how would I implement my method using those notification messages, I thought you're referring me to some part of [the](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation about predicting. I just posted this question in order to make sure, there is no common way to do it. Thanks anyway :)
I'll go with Remy's suggestion.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: The system provides the **entire** infrastructure to implement auto-completion (as pointed out by [Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167773/win32-api-edit-control-text-prediction#comment52224121_32167773)). If you don't know the Windows API, don't feel obliged to answer. Both of your comments go off in the a wrong direction.